# How can I write a matrix using the whole page width in a two-colum document?

Tags: matrices, two-column, arrays

How can I write a big matrix (or array) in the width of the page while using two columns for all paper? I know that for figures (`figure*`) can be used, is there any way to do it for arrays?

Comment: How do you want the matrix to be arranged? Should it start in one column and continue in the other, or should it be separate matrices that run down the page in each column?

Comment: @AstroPig7 : I do not want to be separate and be in next page. I want to be in the same page and use both columns of page.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol)?

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Is it IEEE by any chance?

Comment: why not just enclose the matrix/array in a `figure*` environment?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: good idea! actually it works, however it put the matrix (array) in the beginning of next page. I just want my matrix stay in same place but use both columns of page.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: i use \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}

Comment: @Werner: i am really not sure whether am i allow to use or not.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I want it stays the line that i wrote the code

Comment: And when i use \begin{figures*}[H] to force figure be at the point i wrote the code, then the equation disappears. I also added \usepackage{float} to the beginning of my file

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch from `twocolumn` mode to `onecolumn` mode in the middle of the page. The only mechanism is using the environment `figure*` or `table*`.

If you need such a switch you can work with the great package `multicol`.

Frank Mittelbach answered a similar question some time ago:

[Onecolumn till end of page in twocolumn mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59743/onecolumn-till-end-of-page-in-twocolumn-mode/66606#66606)

Comment: The problem about using either figure* or table*, latex does not let me where to put my array. It just locates it at the beginning of the next page. When i use \begin{figure*}[H] with \usepackage{float} to force it to be the place that i wrote the code, the equation (array) disappears.